# How to add 2 entries to 1 field in phpmyadmin without duplicating that row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Say that im building a DB of candy bars and one of the categories is "Flavor" say that a candy bar has more than 1 flavor, how do i represent that in phpmyadmin without creating a duplicate row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a more complex model:

- candybar table, without flavour row.
- flavours table, only an id, the name, and some other stuff if you want.
- relationship table, containing rows with candybar_id and flavour_id

with this, a candy bar can have more than one flavour, and also a flavour can be associated with more than one candybar. This is a normal N-M relationship.

**UPDATE:**

If you are not familiar with this kind of issues, i recommend that you read [some tutorials on how to model relational databases](https://www.google.es/webhp?tab=ww&ei=B-WgUpvxGaHN7Ab0kYHADw&ved=0CBUQ1S4#q=relational%20database%20modeling%20tutorial).

Comment: my pleasure. thats the usual way in a relational database, so you will find yourself doing this kind of things very often!